# Dropwizard Server shuts down automatically after some time

Tags: java, rest, jetty, microservices, dropwizard

I wrote one java rest microservice using Dropwizard framework.
The service starts fine but if no activity is happening on the microservice, it shuts down automatically with following logs

```
INFO   [15:17:54.165] [dw-240 - GET /uid/requests/be7e2b1c-a694-4a11-b586-
c5082f61c2ef] c.t.u.b.UIDQueryService -  Transformed response for requestId 
[be7e2b1c-a694-4a11-b586-c5082f61c2ef]
INFO   [15:55:43.040] [Thread-14] o.e.j.s.ServerConnector -  Stopped 
application@f5a7226{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
INFO   [15:55:43.042] [Thread-14] o.e.j.s.ServerConnector -  Stopped 
admin@519c6fcc{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8081}
INFO   [15:55:43.043] [Thread-14] o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler -  Stopped 
i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@ee2ae9a{/,null,UNAVAILABLE}
```

From the logs we can see that the server automatically shutdown after some inactivity on microservice. Diff in time between last GET and Server shutdown is about 40 minutes.

I think its some configuration which kills the service after certain inactivity, Does any one has idea about this.

Comment: Try to increase log verbosity or do a strace to catch signal, something is asking to stop your application, this is not default behavior.  What version of dropwizard are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

in the config file configure threads part

```
 maxThreads: 20480
  minThreads: 50
```

https://github.com/armdev/tosptube/blob/master/tosp-auth/src/main/resources/config.yml